# Grails Domain Class with Inheritance fails to set errors after validate

Tags: validation, grails, inheritance, grails-orm

I am experiencing a very strange behaviour in some of our domain classes after upgrading vom grails 2.1.4 to 2.3.11.

The Domain Objects i am talking about use inheritance and also has embedded properties.
Here is a simple outline of the structure we are using

```
abstract class A {
   String normalProperty
   ComplexType embeddedProperty

   static embedded = [ 'embeddedProperty' ]
}

class B extends A {
    String someMoreProperties

    static hasMany = [ cs: C ]
}

class C extends A {
    String evenMoreProperties

    static belongsTo = [ b: B ]
}
```

I can save a instance of B without errors.
When i try to create a C object and add it to the list in B and save B i will get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.setupErrorsProperty(AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.java:100)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractSavePersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(AbstractSavePersistentMethod.java:156)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.java:63)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormInstanceApi.save(HibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:196)
```

I investigated the issue and found out that validation is no longer working.
If I call `b.validate()` or `c.validate()` `b.errors` and `c.errors` will still be null.
This is causing the null pointer exception on save. 
The odd thing is that there will be an errors Object when there is an actual validation error in the object, its only null when validation is passed.

Usually when you validate an entity the errors field will have the value of a `grails.validation.ValidationError` Object. However for my B and C objects the error field will be either null if there was no error or `org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult` if there was an validation error.

Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated .

Comment: I think at first you need investigate what changed in Hibernate and Gorm. Maybe you'll found some info in the release notes.